# Array sort behaves incorrectly in a mobile browser

Tags: angularjs

I've an array of objects which needs to be sorted by email ids, where an email id is an object key. I also have a function to sort. For example:

```
var bills=[name: "somename",email:"email@domain.com", name:"somename2",email:"email2@domain.com"]

/* sort function */
function sortArray(bills,email) {
 bills.sort(function (a,b) {
 return a[email] > b[email];
 });
}
```

The array is sorted by email id in the ascending order when tested in a desktop browser but its not sorted in a mobile browser (IOS:safari & chrome). It appears as it was entered in the array. Interestingly, in the broswer, the array is sorted by email id in the ascending order even before the sort function is applied. I tried the stackoverflow archives and this is the closest that I could get to: [My Angular JS app works in desktop browser, but not in a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210992/my-angular-js-app-works-in-desktop-browser-but-not-in-a-mobile-browser) but it does not seem to address this issue in particular as the other areas of the application is working as expected. I would be grateful if anyone could help me out here. Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Aj

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this using angular filter

```
$scope.array = $filter('orderBy')($scope.array,'payee');
```

payee is one of the object attributes of an object in the array $scope.array.